# The upload part of jbimages works but the image does't appear

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, image-upload, justboil.me

I use jbimages with tinymce. I can select an image,it uploads to the correct folder, but the path looks like this: `src="/uploads/asd.jpg"`

When I open it in a new tab, the URL is `http://users.asd.com/uploads/asd.jpg` and it should look like this: `http://users.asd.com/mysite/uploads/asd.jpg`

When I delete the first `/` with web developer, it works (`src="uploads/asd.jpg"`)
The folder structure is:
admin
   -tinymce
   -js
     ~tinymceconfig.js
   -index.php
plugins
css
uploads
index.php

I really don't understand it.

Jbimages config:
['img_path'] = '/uploads';

It works on localhost and worked 3 weeks ago on the server too, but I had to delete everything and I didn't save it.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your target folder to the root of your website and add the parameter **document_base_url : "http://"** in your tinymce code.